# Installing YouCompleteMe Plugin for VIM under babun on windows

Tags: vim, cygwin, youcompleteme, babun

I am using [babun](http://babun.github.io/) 1.20, ( which uses cygwin under the hood), I am trying to install  [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) Plugin ( for javascript ),I get the following error when I run the following command:

***./install.py***

**Error:**

> 0 [main] cmake 5244 child_info_fork::abort:
>   C:\Users\310127901.babun\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dl
>   l: Loaded to different address: parent(0x7E0000) != child(0x8F0000)
>   [1](http://babun.github.io/)  + 4820 suspended (signal)  ./install.py

**Versions:**

Python : 2.7.8 
cmake  : 3.3.2

I don't have visual studio installed on my machine, and since i want to use this plugin only for Javascript, i guess i dont need it.

Has anybody faced a similar issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Before you waste time, the documentation reports: `JavaScript support: install nodejs and npm and add --tern-completer when calling ./install.py.`and there is no javascript for cygwin

Comment: Use the plugin's documentation and issue tracker.

Comment: @matzeri , I tried that option and got the below error : **./install.py --tern-completer**
      0 [main] cmake 7736 child_info_fork::abort: C:\Users\310127901\.babun\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dl                      l: Loaded to different address: parent(0x7E0000) != child(0x910000)

Comment: You missed the point. There is no javascript on cygwin, so also if you solve the specific issue, the plugin will not work on cygwin vim